# Solr groups include two result

Tags: solr

I've grouping issue in solr. My query is like this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?group.field=PackName&group=true&q=PackName:*&rows=2147483647&start=0&wt=json&indent=true&fl=PackName
```

And the query response like this

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":39,
    "params":{
      "q":"PackName:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"PackName",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"2147483647",
      "wt":"json",
      "group.field":"PackName",
      "group":"true"}},
  "grouped":{
    "PackName":{
      "matches":112559,
      "groups":[{
          "groupValue":"06",
          "doclist":{"numFound":20423,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["06 Delivery Documents - MiniPack"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"08",
          "doclist":{"numFound":105,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["08 DER-PMA-OTC"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"10",
          "doclist":{"numFound":2030,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["10 Vendor Scrap Reports"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"11",
          "doclist":{"numFound":75,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["11 WIP TPL"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"01",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1375,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["01 Documents From Customer"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"02",
          "doclist":{"numFound":22197,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["02 Incoming"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"03",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1771,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["03 Workscope"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"04",
          "doclist":{"numFound":38595,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["04 Module and Part Pictures - V25"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"05",
          "doclist":{"numFound":25899,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["05 Outgoing"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"07",
          "doclist":{"numFound":75,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["07 Engine Status Report"]}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"09",
          "doclist":{"numFound":14,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "PackName":["09 Accessories Work Shop Reports"]}]
          }}]}}
```

The problem is in first group. The first group includes more than once PackName like **06 Delivery Documents - MiniPack** and **06 Delivery Documents - FinalPack**. I don't want to inclued both of them. How can I seperate them? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When indexing the document, add a new field where you've processed the original content into the content you want present. Doing this at runtime will defeat the purpose of using a document search engine like Solr.

You can use [an update processor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) to do this - based on the rules for how you want to go from the first form to the second. Possibly you already have this value from another column in your original data set as well? The other option is to pre-process the value when indexing in the language you're already using to get data into Solr.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how I do it.

Comment: That comment isn't helpful in any way for me to help you further. You'll have to detail WHAT you don't understand, what you've tried to do and where you're running into problems. It's impossible to guess what you don't understand or how anyone can reformat or extend their answer to be more helpful to you without further details.